# facebook c# SDK vb.net issue

Tags: vb.net, facebook-c#-sdk

i have been trying to use this sdk with vb.net with dynamic, using the vb sample thats on the site and im getting an error
 "Public member 'id' on type 'JsonObject' not found." 
thats in the sample GetSampleWithAccessToken referring to is

```
 Dim id = result.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're giving too little context, but it seems that `result` is typed as `JsonObject`, while it should be typed explicitly as `Object` for the dynamic features of VB to kick in.

```
Dim result as Object = ...
Dim id = result.id
```